# How would I issue some ERC20 tokens of newly instantiated ERC20 token

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'm trying to make possible payments in all ERC20 tokens for example USDC - 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48. How would I get some tokens after instantiating this token?

I'm using openzeppelin ERC20 token implementation.

Here is my code

```
event tokenBalance(uint);
  function exchangeOneEtherToERC20(address tokenAddress) public payable {
   require(msg.value == 1 ether, "Should be sent for exchanging exactly 1 ether");
   
   ERC20 token = ERC20(tokenAddress);

   token.approve(msg.sender, 1);
   token.transfer(msg.sender, 1);
   emit tokenBalance(token.balanceOf(msg.sender));
}
```

Comment: You need to call the .approve and .transfer from a wallet with your erc20 token, something like `erc20.connect(depositorSigner).transfer(...)`, but its not clear if you already minted some of the token to some accounts